# Why is the SP Manager Install failing?

Tags: installation, manager

I tried to install Sharepoint Manager 2010, which I got from [here](https://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/51438)

...but it failed with:

[image]

Where is the LoaderExceptions property, or does anybody know what the issue might be? This is a Windows 7, 64-bit machine that I'm trying to install it on.

Should I revert to the pre-release version [here](https://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/35932)?

Answer (score 3):

As per the SP Manager Installation Requirement. It should install on One of SharePoint Web Front end, this required SharePoint foundation 2010 or 2013 version installed.

How to install:

- Download the ZIP file and unpack on a SharePoint front-end Server.*
- Run the SharePoint Manager 2013.exe program.

(*) This program has to run on a server where SharePoint Foundation 2010 or 2013 is installed.

Another thing, Be sure that you are the server and SharePoint administrator.

Check the ReadMe document in the ZIP folder.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but SharePoint Manager is an executable, it doesn't install. Do you have SharePoint on your windows 7 machine ?

Comment: I don't have SP proper installed yet.

Comment: I don't have SP proper installed yet. Okay, so the question is, "Why does it fail to run"?

Comment: SharePoint Manager must run in a machine on which SharePoint is already installed because it uses the Server Side code to access SharePoint elements.

You can install SharePoint on Windows 7 (which I highly not recommand) but I don't know then if SP Manager will work or not.